# Halakhic Home "Hacks"

Tags: halacha, home-house

I am looking to build a home in the distant future and am looking for advice on some ways for when building the home to make it more comfortable in the Halakhic sense.

examples of ideas I had so far:

- building a solar heated water tank in order to use hot water on Shabbat (or some other idea of a similar nature)
- building a halakhic *mechitza* next to a toilet so I can wash *nagelvasser* in the bathroom.
- building a pergola/deck combo attached to house or something to make sukkah building easier and more comfortable

etc.

Any ideas, or suggestions would be great!

Comment: Note the solar heated water tank still creates issues of *bishul*, cooking the water when mixing cold and hot water. See e.g., [here](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=6226) and [here](http://www.zomet.org.il/eng/?CategoryID=250&ArticleID=103) for a possible solution